# sort a foreach list to unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, tcl, eggdrop

I have this output from mysql and i want sort to the highst unix timestamp first. ctime variable is unix timestamp

i have addet a secend foreach i $output { to my code

```
bind pub "-|-" !grptop add:grptop
proc add:grptop {nick host handle channel text} {

global mysql

set output [AA BB CC DD EE FF]
foreach i $output {
set sql "SELECT * FROM name WHERE grp = '$i' ORDER BY ctime DESC LIMIT 1"
set result [mysqlsel $mysql $sql -list]
set record [lindex $result 0];
set name [lindex $record 2];
set ctime [lindex $record 6];
set date [clock format [lindex [split $ctime] 0] -format {%d:%m:%Y}];
putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :\00314\[\00307$i\00314\]\00300 >\00314 [getLongTime $ctime] \00300> \00314$name"
}   
}

proc getLongTime {ctime} {
set date [clock format [lindex [split $ctime] 0] -format {%d:%m:%Y}];
   set elapsed [duration [expr [clock seconds] - $ctime]];
regsub -all { second(s)?} $elapsed s elapsed;
regsub -all { minute(s)?} $elapsed m elapsed;
regsub -all { hour(s)?} $elapsed h elapsed;
regsub -all { day(s)?} $elapsed d elapsed;
regsub -all { week(s)?} $elapsed w elapsed;
regsub -all { month(s)?} $elapsed m elapsed;
regsub -all { year(s)?} $elapsed y elapsed;
return $elapsed;
}
```

output its :

```
<testbot> [AA] > 1d 3h 37m 41s > testname1
<testbot> [CC] > 1y 17w 2d 7h 25m 16s > testname2
<testbot> [DD] > 2h 45m 7s > testname3
<testbot> [BB] > 1d 21h 57m 15s > testname4
<testbot> [EE] > 42m 40s > testname5
```

and not sorted in time

Comment: Why exactly is the output *not* sorted, it appears to me in perfect descending time order?

Comment: oh sorry, that was a coincidence..

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in the logic of your program, I am afraid: each query is limited to returning only one record (`LIMIT 1`, per group `grp`). So, `ORDER BY` will not return a result set of timestamp-ordered entries per group, just the first of the ordered entries per group. Besides, this way the entries will not be ordered globally across all groups. What is your intention? You should add the `sql` tag, as this is only marginally, if at all, related to `tcl`.

Comment: ORDER BY ctime DESC LIMIT 1, i have set this because i just want the latest from each grp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in my comment, this is due to the query (`SELECT`) not operating in line with your expectations:

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE grp = '$i' ORDER BY ctime DESC LIMIT 1
```

This returns the most recent (`ctime`) for each group (`grp`), but it does not provide for an ordering across groups. For this, and depending on your exact schema, you must rewrite your query to sth. like:

```
SELECT n1.*
FROM name n1
WHERE ctime = (SELECT MAX(n2.ctime)
               FROM name n2
               WHERE n2.grp = n1.grp);
```

- The inner `SELECT` obtains the most recent (highest, max) timestamp for a given `grp`.
- The outer `SELECT` obtains the details of entries matching the most recent (highest, max) timestamp for a given group.
- You might want to add `LIMIT 1` too, to the outher `SELECT`, in case your data as multiple entries per timestamp (timestamp granularity).

This is not about `tcl`, however, that is not to say that you could not do the grouping/ filtering in Tcl per se.

Comment: @MikeShiwa So yoou might want to accept the answer then? Also, the `tcl` tag is not needed IMO.